# An idea for mobile phones screen utility option

Tags: international

I have an idea! (Just) in my mind.it is a very useful idea when it will b practicly use in  for upcoming mobie phone which will be more convenient to use there phons easily...

So shall I patent my idea (non documentationly) at international n what I have to do?

Comment: Please proofread and edit your question. You may want to consult with a patent attorney.

Comment: Yes I want to consult

Comment: It is an idea just but,it will b a big implementation.

Comment: Since you can’t disclose your idea here without potentially losing patentability, there is little advice we can provide. You should actually talk face to face with an actual patent attorney.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what you're asking at the moment. If you could revise your question to be a little more targeted, we may be able to be provide you a useful answer.